# Entity Framework Core error on Insert when exists a foreign key to a View

Tags: entity-framework-core

This is my model (semplified):

PRAT is the main table

```
public partial class PRAT
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PRATICA { get; set; }
    public int ANNO { get; set; }
    public string VARIANTE { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID")]
    public VW_PRATICHE_CONTIPO VW_PRATICHE_CONTIPO { get; set; }
}
```

VW_PRATICHE_CONTIPO is a View (not a table!) in the database that contains some data related to PRAT table

```
public class VW_PRATICHE_CONTIPO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DATAPRES { get; set; }
    public string PROTGEN { get; set; }
    public string TIPO { get; set; }
    public string TIPOEXTRA { get; set; }
    public string TIPOISTANZA { get; set; }
    public string TIPOPRAT { get; set; }
}
```

The one-to-one relation between the table and the View is based on the ID field.

I need this because I want to do a query like this:

```
context.PRAT.Include(x=> x.VW_PRATICHE_CONTIPO)
```

This query works as exptected.

The problem happens when I try to save a new entity in PRAT.

When i do this:

```
context.PRAT.Add(prat);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I got this error:

The property 'ID' on entity type 'PRAT' has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

If I remove the navigation property from PRAT all works fine, but I can't do the Include in my Query.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you.